# IBOutlet is nil, but it is connected in storyboard (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, swift2

I am trying to show some content in the cell of the `UITableView`. The program does reach the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: EventTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventCell") as! EventTableViewCell

    let date = self.eventArray[indexPath.row].startTime
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let minutes = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: date)
    var minutesString: String
    if (minutes == 0) {
        minutesString = "00"
    } else {
        minutesString = String(calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: date))
    }
    let hours = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: date)
//this next line of code works, i see cell text:
//  cell.textLabel?.text = self.eventArray[indexPath.row].title + " - \(hours):\(minutesString)"

//these lines do not work, see empty cells:
    cell.cellLable?.text = self.eventArray[indexPath.row].title + " - \(hours):\(minutesString)"
    cell.textField?.text = self.eventArray[indexPath.row].notes
    return cell
}
```

I have properly connected the **outlets**: 
[image]

If I set breakpoint, the cell appears to be the `EventTableViewCell`, but both `cellLabel` and `textField` are nil: 
[image]

My table view connections look like this:

[image]

Connection inspector for the eventCell here:
[image]

I have also made Content View background color blue, but it seems like I don't see the whole Content view in my cell.

My custom cell class looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you using autoLayout in TableView? If Yes, then please check autolayout constraint of your views.  Please also check that you have map delegate & datasource of tableview to respective ViewController in Storyboard.

Comment: checked: dont use autolayout constraints, and delegate and datasource are connected

Comment: can you show your custom cell cade?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS updated the post now

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the correct identifier for your cell in IB. Let cell... is returning nil so that appears to be your problem.

```
let cell: EventTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventCell") as! EventTableViewCell
```

Comment: it has correct identifier, I checked it in the first place.

Comment: cell is not nil, cell is object of the type EventTableViewCell, it is weird that the first line with default cell's text works: cell.textLabel?.text = ... but my cell.cellLable?.text = ... does not.

Comment: Can you show the connections for all of the cell's outlets by highlighting the eventCell and then showing the Connections Inspector?

Comment: I saw somewhere that renaming folders can cause this, so I removed reference to storyboard, and added it again, did not help.

Answer (score 0):

cell.textLabel works since you inherit the UITabelViewCell Class. You are getting a UITabelViewCell as reference - that is granted.

Create a strong reference to your label within the scope.
Place a breakpoint and validate what you are actually getting as cell. (indeed the correct subclass of yours or something generic.)

If the cell object is correct, but you don't get the label it must be outlet related. 
In some cases in Swift I came upon the need to change the OUTLET for an UIElement from weak to strong.

If yes, only the properties of the label remain as cause. Give the label a background color. It's layout is actually visible? (eg.: hidden = NO, alpha = 1, frame/constrains render it visible and so on.)